# Sending a request to a server asynchronously involving akka

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future

I want to make a request to a server asynchronously involving actors. Say I have 2 actors:

```
 class SessionRetriever extends Actor {
  import SessionRetriever._

  def receiver = {
    Get => 
      val s = getSessionIdFromServer() // 1
      sender ! Result(s)               // 2
  }

  def getSessionIdFromServer(): String = { ... } // 3
}

object SessionRetriever {
  object Get
  object Result(s: String)
}
```

And

```
class RequestSender extends Actor {
  val sActor = context actorOf Props[SessionRetriever]

  def receiver = {
    // get session id
    val sesId = sActor ! SessionRetriever.Get 
    val res = sendRequestToServer(sesId)      
    logToFile(res)                            

    context shutdown sActor       
  }


  def sendRequestToServer(sessionId: String): String = { .... } 
}
```

My questions:

```
val s = getSessionIdFromServer() // 1
sender ! Result(s)               // 2
```

1) **getSessionIdFromServer()** does a synchronous request to the server. I think it would be much better make a request asynchronous, correct? So it will return **Future[String]** instead of a plain **String**.

2) How do I make asynchronous: by using an **AsyncHttpClient** (if I recall correctly its name) or by wrapping its synchronous body into **Future { }** ?

3) Should I use **blocking { }** block ? If yes, then where exactly: inside its body or here `val s = blocking { getSessionIdFromServer() }` ?

P.S. I'd like not to use `async { }` and `await { }` at this point because they are quite high level functions and after all they are build on top on `Futures`.

Answer (score 2):

you might try this non-blocking way

```
def receive = {
    Get => 
      //assume getSessionIdFromServer() run aysnchronize
      val f: Future[String] = getSessionIdFromServer()
      val client = sender //keep it local to use when future back
      f onComplete {
        case Success(rep) => client ! Result(rep)
        case Failure(ex) => client ! Failed(ex)
      }
 }
```

Comment: 1) Why not to use blocking { } ? 2) Why to use "!" instead of "?" ?

Comment: See my answer: it might not block the actor's thread, but if all you do is wrap `getSessionIdFromServer` in a `Future{}` block then you are still blocking a thread.

Comment: you could use blocking in getSessionIdFromServer(); here is just the result Future got from that method; ! means non expecting result from the client, ? expects the result, and will block the processing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your first comment. What "might not block the actor's thread"? Why am I blocking the thread by Future?

Comment: @Alex actually, if you combine my answer with Arnaud's, you should get the complete one; you see all run async, and non-blocking. I understand that blocking{} is like indicator, that you have something will block the thread running, like Thread.sleep(); then you wrap it with blocking{}, the executor may have some strategy to deal with it; but it doesn't change the processing; but, here, there is non-blocking at all; all run asynchronously, so no blocking{} necessary;

Comment: His answer is ok but I'd like something more at a deeper level in order to understand how it works. Do you mean Future { } might also completely block its own (spawned) thread and there is no way to deal with this except using "blocking { }"?

Answer (score 1):

1) If `getSessionIdFromServer()` is blocking then you should execute it asynchronously from your `receive` function, otherwise your actor will block each time it receives a new request and will always wait until it receives a new session before processing the next request.

2) Using a Future will "move" the blocking operation to a different thread. So, your actor will not be blocked and will be able to keep processing incoming requests - that's good -, however you are still blocking a thread - not so great. Using the AsyncHttpClient is a good idea. You can explore other non-blocking httpClient, like PlayWebService.

3) I am not quite familiar with `blocking` so not sure I should advise anything here. From what I understand, it will tell the thread pool that the operation is blocking and that it should spawn a temporary new thread to handle it - this avoids having all your workers being blocked. Again, if you do that your actor will not blocked, but you are still blocking a thread while getting the session from the server.

To summarize: just use an async http client in `getSessionIdFromServer` if it is possible. Otherwise, use either `Future{}` or `blocking`.

Comment: 1) It's probably blocking, isn't it?

Comment: Well, it depends how it's implemented. But if it returns a `String` yes it most likely is. If you use the AsyncHttpClient you will return a `Future[String]` instead.

Comment: well, AsyncHttpClient has also to deal with blocking operations somehow because it's just a library. If it does that successfully then there is such the way. I'd like to use its way of dealing with blocking operations myself. Do you know what its way is?

Comment: The async client uses non blocking io so no, it's not blocking. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel anyway. It's there, use it. You can read its documentation to learn more about it.

Comment: and what does non blocking io use? I don't want to use it in order to learn how low-level operations work.

Comment: OK, at this point you can use Google to learn about nio, and if you encounter a problem start a new thread with a different question. You got several good answers to this very question about actors.

Answer (score 1):

To do an asynchronous call with AsyncHttpClient you could deal with the java Future via a scala Promise.

```
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
    import scala.concurrent.Promise
    import java.util.concurrent.Executor

    object WebClient {

      private val client = new AsyncHttpClient

      case class BadStatus(status: Int) extends RuntimeException

      def get(url: String)(implicit exec: Executor): Future[String] = {
        val f = client.prepareGet(url).execute();
        val p = Promise[String]()
        f.addListener(new Runnable {
          def run = {
            val response = f.get
            if (response.getStatusCode / 100 < 4)
              p.success(response.getResponseBodyExcerpt(131072))
            else p.failure(BadStatus(response.getStatusCode))
          }
        }, exec)
        p.future
      }

      def shutdown(): Unit = client.close()
 }

 object WebClientTest extends App {
   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
   WebClient get "http://www.google.com/" map println foreach (_ => WebClient.shutdown())
 }
```

And then deal with the future completion via a callback.

Credit for the code to the awesome reactive programming course at Coursera.